PyTest - How to execute set of instructions at the very end of each test (so after other fixtures teardown)
Is there a way to execute a set of instructions after each test (at the end of the test execution including fixtures teardown for that test)?
And not autouse=True fixture is not an option, teardown instructions do not execute always after other teardowns
So the main goal is to execute the fixture prior to any other fixtures, without having it as a dependency somewhere, just to somehow, when a specific test starts, this fixture has to go first prior to anything else

Using the yield keyword is very powerful in fixture setup. See pytest documentation.
If you combine this with an dependency system in your fixtures you can also guarantee an order in tearing down. See source.
import pytest


@pytest.fixture()
def main_dependency():
    # setup
    my_variable = object()
    print("first to create")

    # hand over control flow using yield
    yield my_variable

    # cleanup after control comes back
    print("last to delete")
    del my_variable


@pytest.fixture()
def sub_dependency(main_dependency):
    # setup
    my_variable = object()
    print("second to create")

    # hand over control flow using yield
    yield my_variable

    # cleanup after control comes back
    print("first to delete")
    del my_variable


def test_fixtures(sub_dependency):
    assert True

Run this with pytest -s to ensure log output.
first to create
second to create

first to delete
last to delete


Well this does not ensure that my fixture is the last one to execute, with this, I had times when the fixture teardown was prior to other fixtures teardowns

This isn't very clear from your question, maybe you could amend it a bit. I'll amend my answer to include fixture order.

I see, but having it as a dependency dosen't help my in my case unfortunatelly, i need it to execute exactly before any other fixture or test insctruction

So there's a nuance here that's not clear.
Does it have to run once before/after every tests individually?
•Or*
Does it have to run once before/after all of the tests have been executed?
There's a great chapter on how to order your tests using scopes (of which Autouse=True is a special case). See here.
So if the answer is A you're going to have to do something with dependencies. If the answer is B you can use the scope keyword to run it once for an entire "session".
